# Anyone have a React Netflix Slider functional component version?

Tags: reactjs, slider

I am new to React.
I just learn React after functional component, I want build a netflix like project using this slider:

`````
````https://codepen.io/BrunoIF/pen/KKpGOrq````
`````

But, I am having a trouble read that code beacuse is using a class component, anyone have slider like that in functional component?

Thank you for your response.